# java, работа с файлом БД (mysql) напрямую (без локального сервера)

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, sql-server-localdb

Итак добрые люди, прошу сразу не судить строго ибо только учусь писать код)
Вопрос следующий - есть некое javaFX приложение которое хранит свои данные в БД mysql, но сейчас оно подключается к ней через локальный сервер(open server), так вот, что нужно делать чтобы работать конкретно  с файлом БД без локального сервера, чтобы в итоге этот файл БД можно было "сшить" с программой, запихнуть в .exe и спокойно запускать его на другом пк без установки локального сервера и подключения к нему.
Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вопрос состоит в том, как подключиться к бд из кода, то след образом:

```
//example
Class.forName("some_jdbc.driver");
try (Connection connecton = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from table")) {

  //some code
} catch (SQLException ignored) {}
```

Если вы из серверной бд пытаетесь сделать локальную, боюсь, с mySql так не выйдет - используйте SQLite

Comment: боюсь, что вопрос был "как мне использовать серверную СУБД без серверной СУБД", поэтому валидна только вторая часть ответа :)

Comment: тогда ткни галочку если помогло!)

Comment: боюсь, комментарий выше был не от автора вопроса. Хотя галочку он ткнул :)